# How do I use PHP to detect a button click and open an new page?

Tags: php, html

I was wondering if someone can help me. I am trying to write some PHP code so that when I click on a button in one page, upload.php, the button click is detected and I am redirected to another page, processing.php. I am following along another tutorial and I have triple checked, I don't see what I have done wrong, but the button click is not being detected as it is in the video.

This is the code for my upload.php file:

```
<?php include_once('includes/header.php');?>

<?php include_once('includes/classes/VideoDetailsFormProvider.php');?>

<div class="column">

<!-- //calling PHP function to create upload form -->
<?php

//create variable and assign value
$formProvier = new VideoDetailsFormProvider($con);

//call function
echo $formProvier->createUploadForm();



?>

</div>

<?php include_once('includes/footer.php');?>
```

This is the relevant code from my additional class VideoDetailsFormProvider.php:

```
class VideoDetailsFormProvider{

    private $con;

    //create constructor and pass $con variable to it
    public function __construct($con){
        $this->con = $con;
    }

    //creating a function to create the upload form
    public function createUploadForm(){
        $fileInput = $this->createFileInput();
        $titleInput = $this->createTitleInput();
        $descriptionInput = $this->createDescriptionInput();
        $privacyInput = $this->createPrivacyInput();
        $categoryInput = $this->createCategoryInput();
        $uploadButton = $this->createUploadButton();
        return "
            <form action='processing.php' method='POST'>
                $fileInput
                $titleInput
                $descriptionInput
                $privacyInput
                $categoryInput
                $uploadButton
            </form> 
        ";
    }

private function createUploadButton(){
        $html = "<button name='uploadButton' class='btn btn-primary'>Upload Video</button>";
        return $html;
    }
```

And this is what I have in my processing.php file:

```
<?php include_once('includes/header.php');

//check for submission of the form or button is pressed
if(!isset($_POST['uploadButton'])){
    echo "No form data has been set";
    
}else{
    
}


?>
```

When I click the button object, nothing happens. In the video I am transferred to processing.php and the echo message is not displayed. Or at least I should be, but that doesn't happen. I did try to check here to see if I could find some answers, a few things I tried didn't work out. Does anyone have any ideas about something I might be missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: PHP is a serverside language, you don't detect UI changes with it, unless you are using something like `PHP-GTK` which I haven't seen in the last ten years.

Comment: Show the source of the generated html  (with the form element) please

Comment: In order for the button to take you to processing.php it needs to be inside `<form>` tags, and the action attribute needs to point to processing.php. Please show your html.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your upload button, when you use an html form it has to be submitted to the php processing page, try:-

```
private function createUploadButton(){
    $html = "<button type='submit' name='uploadButton' class='btn btn-primary'>Upload Video</button>";
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: I was just about to answer that +1

Comment: `type="submit"` is irrelevant here. That is the default behavior.

Comment: @EternalHour but it's not obvious that it's the default behavior. I have answered at least two questions where people didn't realize why their form was submitting when they clicked a button

Comment: @JuanMendes - It makes sense to point it out if they are sending the form via JS because that's not the behavior you want. In this case, the form needs to submit which it is already doing.

Comment: @EternalHour I don't follow, I'm saying adding something that is already a default may be clearer to the person reading because most aren't aware of a default

Comment: My point is, it may make it clearer to the reader but it won't solve the OPs issue.